# How to specify "or" in XML?

Tags: xml

Ok I'm new at learning XML. I was practicing and wondered about this.
How do I specify "Item" value below to use an alternate item like "item 2" if "item1" is not available. In result, I want "or" or "if" system in XML, is it possible?

Here's the code:

```
<property class="UpgradeBlock">
    <property name="ToBlock" value="Block2"/>
    <property name="Item" value="item1"/>
    <property name="ItemCount" value="1"/>
    <property name="UpgradeHitCount" value="3"/>
</property>
```

Comment: XML has no notion of items not being available.

Comment: are you writing business logic in XML?

Comment: If you mean that the 'reader' will have an alternate, you can specify that in your meta data. In your example `<property name="Item" value="item1"/>` Then add bellow `<property name="Alternate_Item" value="item2"/>`

Answer (score 0):

XML is a markup language, not a programming language, so at its core it's a means to represent data and not business logic. You'll need to implement your logic some other way.